# android studio can not open

Tags: performance, android-studio, jvm

when I click on the android studio icon cannot open and show error.
I change the setting of the android studio from click Help > Edit Custom VM Options to open your studio.vmoptions file and write
XmxheapSize-Xmx2g
After than android studio show that error and can not open.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Start</kbd>, type Path, and click Enter to select **Edit environment variables** for your account.

You will see **Environment Variables..** option in **System Properties** panel, click that.

In **System Variables** part click new and in `Variable name` part type **JAVA_HOME**
and in `Variable value` part you should copy and paste the path of your **JDK** and then press Ok and restart your system. look at the images for better understanding:

[image: path of jdk]

[image]

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you :) @zubairkhanshinwari